# FLEX- disable the cursor click event on busyCursor

Tags: apache-flex, click, cursor, busy-cursor

I am using a flex2 in a web application. I have added a busy-cursor in my application successful but I need to disable the cursor click event as long as the cursor animates.
Can I do this? How can I do it?

I am new to flex. Please provide me a sample code. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of off the top of my head.  But you can always remove the "click" listener to the components on the page.

E.g.,

```
myComponent.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEventDoThis);
```

It's a pain though, since you would have to do this for every visual component.

What I've done in the past, is just make the component.enable = false.  That way, it greys out and doesn't listen to any events.

```
myComponent.enable = false;
```

Just remember to re-enable it when you're done with the busy cursor.

```
myComponent.enable = true;
```